# Conditional Operator in value attribute workaround

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to do the equivalent of:

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{playerBean==null?null:playerBean.wavRecorded}"/>
```

However, the conditional operator cannot be used in value tags according to:

[Using conditional operator in h:inputText value and h:commandButton actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609493/using-conditional-operator-in-hinputtext-value-and-hcommandbutton-actionlisten)

I tried doing part 2 of the answer in the above article, but ran into issues.

I'd like to know how to do part 1 in the answer, but I don't need to use actionlisteners etc.. Is there a simple workaround to getting a conditional statement in another tag to populate the value in this hidden input?

Thanks

Comment: Feels too much like a XY problem. You actually want to set it as a JS variable, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use `<c:set>` as indicated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6441415/5482166) answer. It would look something like this:

```
<c:set var="wavRecorded" value="#{playerBean==null?null:playerBean.wavRecorded}" scope="request" />
```

And then:

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{wavRecorded}"/>
```

Comment: I did this, but now I'm getting errors finding the element for some reason.. let me set up a fiddle