# Illegal Syntax for Set Operation for Primefaces Boolean CheckBox?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

Does the below EL expression for value is a valid one?

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{!bean.isCreateGroup}" id="checkBoxCreateSecurityGrpKey">
```

I'm getting the error as

```
javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException:/pages/popup.xhtml @503,170 value="#{!bean.isCreateGroup}": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
```

Answer (score 6):

The expression `value="#{!bean.isCreateGroup}"` is not valid here because the value attribute of [SelectBooleanCheckBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectBooleanCheckbox.html) must be a [javax.el.ValueExpression](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/2.1/docs/jsp-2_1-pfd2/javax/el/ValueExpression.html) that can both get and set a value (l-value expression).

From the linked Javadoc of ValueExpression:

> Not all r-value expressions can be used as l-value expressions (e.g. "${1+1}" or "${firstName} ${lastName}")

And from the Expression Language Specification 2.1:

> The valid syntax for an lvalue is a subset of the valid syntax for an rvalue. In
>   particular, an lvalue can only consist of either a single variable (e.g. ${name}) or a
>   property resolution on some object, via the . or [] operator (e.g.
>   ${employee.name}).

To make it crystal clear, the expression should represent a bean property:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{bean.aBooleanProperty}" ... />
```

In your case, the simplest solution is to use another Boolean variable in your bean that has the opposite value, e.g. something like `Boolean notCreateGroup` (by the way, why a component referenced with `checkBoxCreateSecurityGrpKey` should have a value opposite to a variable named `createGroup`?).

**Se also:**

[Using conditional operator in h:inputText value and h:commandButton actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609493/using-conditional-operator-in-hinputtext-value-and-hcommandbutton-actionlisten)